# Como obter o nome de uma variável como string em Go?

Tags: variáveis, golang

Existe alguma forma de obter o nome de uma variável em *Go* como *string*?

```
var progzila int
```

Como eu poderia obter nome da variável acima, é possível?

Comment: Por que precisa disto? Ela é local ou faz parte de uma estrutura?

Comment: Ela é local, preciso mostrar o nome dela no console. Em C# existe o operador `nameof` para obter o nome de uma variável. Existe algo similar em Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe nada parecido com o `nameof` do C#, inclusive porque esse operador não existe para fazer o que deseja, ele é uma forma de evitar erros bobos em manutenção quando troca o nome da variável. Seria bom GO ter, mas em geral as linguagens não se preocupam com esses detalhes.

O fato é que em variáveis locais você não precisa disto, é útil, mas não precisa, você sabe o nome da variável. Se nunca trocar o nome dela não terá problemas em ter uma *string* criada na mão, se trocar o nome da variável (raro ser necessário se ela foi bem pensada e geralmente não mudar não causa muito problema), só precisa tomar mais cuidado e mudar também no literal *string*, se a função é pequena a chance de errar é bem pequena. Você sempre sabe o nome de algo que acabou de usar no código. Isso vale para qualquer linguagem.

Se achava que precisava saber o nome da variável desta forma estava fazendo algo errado. Isto costuma valer também para nomes de várias de estruturas. É possível obter o nome da variável nessa circunstância com reflexão, mas quase sempre o uso de reflexão é gambiarra, porque a informação está lá também, você tem ela na mão, em alguns casos pode ser útil porque ela não está de forma tão simples e mudanças podem provocar manutenção um pouco maior, mas voxê troca performance e robustez por menos digitação. Tem outras ferramentas que dão a menor digitação sem comprometer outros pontos.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como obter o nome da variável (talvez com `unsafe`? mas acho que nem assim). Porém, é possível obter o nome de um elemento de um `struct`.

Considerando que tenha:

```
type MeuStruct struct {
    progzila int
}
```

Poderia usar o `val.Type().Field(i).Name` do `Reflect`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MeuStruct struct {
    progzila int
}

func main() {
    ms := &MeuStruct{progzila: 42}

    val := reflect.ValueOf(ms).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Name)
    }
}
```

Assim *printaria*:

> progzila

[Teste aqui.](https://play.golang.org/p/v1bA8zaporB)

---

Não é a mesma coisa, não deve atingir o mesmo objetivo, mas é o que acredito ser mais próximo disponível.